# Отметить все чекбоксы с определённым классом

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Такой вопрос - есть форма с кучей чекбоксов, типа такой

```
<form>
<input type checkbox" class="class1 class2" />
<input type checkbox" class="class2" />
<input type checkbox" class="class1" /> 
<input type checkbox" class="class1 class2" />
<input type checkbox" class="class1" />
```

И есть две кнопки

```
<button>1111</button> <button>2222</button>
```

По нажатию на первую кнопку должны выбираться все чекбоксы с классом class1 (т. е. в примере - 1,3,4 и 5), а при нажатии на вторую - с классом class2 (т.е. в примере - 1,2 и 4), причем, нажатие одной кнопки убирает отметки, установленные другой кнопкой.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать?

Comment: Чистый `javascript` или `jquery`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if (e.target.hasAttribute('data-class')) {
    var button = e.target;
    var className = button.getAttribute('data-class');
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      checkboxes[i].checked = checkboxes[i].classList.contains(className) ? true : false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" class="class1 class2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="class2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="class1" /> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="class1 class2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="class1" /> 
  <button type='button' data-class='class1'>Class 1</button>
  <button type='button' data-class='class2'>Class 2</button>
</form>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, вариант подошел. А не подскажете ли еще? Допустим, вместо некоторых чекбоксов у меня будут обычные числовые инпуты. Можно ли их значения увеличивать на определённое число по тому же принципу?

Comment: конечно. получаем value инпута, в дата атрибуты кнопок  можно записать например plus и minus, и делать проверку, если равен plus то прибавляем, иначе отнимаем, и записываем в value новое значение.

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью jQuery.

```js
function checkElements(classname) {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass(classname)) {
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="class1 class2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="class2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="class1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="class1 class2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="class1" />
<button onclick="checkElements('class1')">111</button>
<button onclick="checkElements('class2')">222</button>
```